# PMI formula throws error

Tags: equations, errors

With

```
\begin{equation*}
PMI\left(w_{1};w_{2}\right) 
=\log _{2} \dfrac{P(\llbracket w_{1},\rrbracket w_{2})} {P(\llbracket w_{1}) P(\rrbracket w_{2})}
\end{equation*}
```

I get an “undefined control sequence” error. Can anybody help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Questions need to be in English, but more importantly, just showing a fragment of code won't usually give enough information to help you. Minimally you need to show us *what* control sequence was undefined. If I put this fragment into a small document loading just `amsmath` it shows that `\llbracket` is undefined. If that's the error you're getting then add `\usepackage{stmaryrd}` to your document preamble.

Comment: Also, the error will tell you what control sequence was undefined.  The next line in the log will have the line in your tex file ending with the undefined control sequence.  (If you're on Overleaf, you'll need to read through the explanatory paragraph first.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the `\llbracket` and `\rrbracket` macros, it's necessary to load either the [stmaryrd](https://ctan.org/pkg/stmaryrd?lang=en) or the [fourier](https://ctan.org/pkg/fourier) package. (Loading the `fourier` math package will also affect other parts of math typography in your document.) To use the `\dfrac` macro and the `equation*` environment, it's necessary to load the [amsmath](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
% for '\dfrac' macro and 'equation*' environment:
\usepackage{amsmath}  
% for '\llbracket' and '\rrbracket' macros:
\usepackage{stmaryrd} % or: \usepackage{fourier}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\mathrm{PMI}(w_{1};w_{2})
=\log_{2} \dfrac{P(\llbracket w_{1},\rrbracket w_{2})}%
                {P(\llbracket w_{1}) P(\rrbracket w_{2})}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```